# Allow nulls / de-duplicate within multi-table join? T-SQL

Tags: sql, ssis, sql-server-2012

I was wondering if there is a way in either SSIS or T-SQL (SQL Server 2012) to easily return non-duplicate data when doing a multi-table join (per-column, not per row)

I am trying to denormalize / flatten a bunch of data for conversion into a warehouse and I am winding up duplicating a ton of data. I'm hoping there is a sort of rollup/summary function or a design concept I am missing that can help me when merging multiple tables to a single destination.

**Example**

Let's say for example I have three tables: CUSTOMERS, CUSTOMER_ADDRESSES and CUSTOMER_ACCOUNTS. They and their data look like this:

> ### CUSTOMERS
>
> ```
> CUST_ID   NAME
> 1         Burton Guster
> ```
>
> ### CUSTOMER_ADDRESSES
>
> ```
> CUST_ID   ADDR_SEQ    ADDRESS
> 1         1           123 Awesome St
> 1         2           456 Fake St
> ```
>
> ### CUSTOMER_ACCOUNTS
>
> ```
> CUST_ID   ACCT_SEQ    ACCT_TYPE    ACCOUNT_OPEN_DT
> 1         1           TAP          1/1/1989
> 1         2           PHARMA       1/1/2010
> ```

I join them using a query like this:

```
SELECT a.CUST_ID, a.NAME, b.ADDRESS, c.ACCT_TYPE, c.ACCOUNT_OPEN_DT
FROM CUSTOMERS a
JOIN CUSTOMER_ADDRESSES b on a.CUST_ID = b.CUST_ID
JOIN CUSTOMER_ACCOUNTS c on a.CUST_ID = c.CUST_ID
```

Obviously each row joins to each row and as expected my output looks like this:

```
ID  NAME            ADDRESS         ACCT_TYPE   ACCT_OPEN_DT
1   Burton Guster   123 Awesome St  TAP         1/1/1989
1   Burton Guster   123 Awesome St  PHARMA      1/1/2010
1   Burton Guster   456 Fake St     TAP         1/1/1989
1   Burton Guster   456 Fake St     PHARMA      1/1/2010
```

Is there any way for me to get something like this instead?:

```
ID  NAME            ADDRESS         ACCT_TYPE   ACCT_OPEN_DT
1   Burton Guster   123 Awesome St  TAP         1/1/1989
1   NULL            456 Fake St     PHARMA      1/1/2010
```

The goal being to group each column, returning the distinct value per column only once. The larger set would be grouped by the customer ID.

Thank you

Comment: Why would you give up on the name in the second row?

Comment: So do you throw out the row information with "TAP" or "PHARMA"? Why?

Comment: I appears that your extension tables have a sequence number added to them. Is there logic behind the value and thus you need to factor the SEQ number in across the joins? It doesn't feel like flattening your doing is the type of flattening I'd do were I to create a data warehouse. Any chance your design needs tuning?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, it can be done, although it's kinda awkward to do... :-)

You can use `ROW_NUMBER()` to get a running row number per costumer from each table independently. Then you can use these row numbers to bring the data together:

```
;WITH custCTE AS (
  SELECT CUST_ID, NAME, 1 AS CUST_ROW_N
  FROM CUSTOMERS
),
addrCTE AS (
  SELECT CUST_ID, ADDRESS, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY CUST_ID ORDER BY ADDR_SEQ) CUST_ROW_N
  FROM CUSTOMER_ADDRESSES
),
acctCTE AS (
  SELECT CUST_ID, ACCT_TYPE, ACCOUNT_OPEN_DT, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY CUST_ID ORDER BY ACCT_SEQ) CUST_ROW_N
  FROM CUSTOMER_ACCOUNTS
)
SELECT COALESCE(a.CUST_ID, b.CUST_ID, c.CUST_ID), a.NAME, b.ADDRESS, c.ACCT_TYPE, c.ACCOUNT_OPEN_DT
FROM custCTE a FULL JOIN addrCTE b ON
  a.CUST_ID = b.CUST_ID AND a.CUST_ROW_N = b.CUST_ROW_N FULL JOIN acctCTE c ON
  (b.CUST_ID = c.CUST_ID AND b.CUST_ROW_N = c.CUST_ROW_N) OR (a.CUST_ID = c.CUST_ID AND a.CUST_ROW_N = c.CUST_ROW_N)
```

Here's an [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/90b18/15)

Comment: I don't think you need `custCTE`.  It seems unlikely that he will have addresses or accounts without customers.  I would just use `FROM Customer a LEFT JOIN addrCTE b ON a.CUST_ID = b.CUST_ID LEFT JOIN acctCTE c ON a.CUST_ID = c.CUST_ID AND b.CUST_ROW_N = c.CUST_ROW_N`.

Comment: Thank you both! I was wondering if either of you might be able to explain the joins you're using and why? Amit - you joined `a->b` then `b->c`. Why not `a->b`, `a->c`? Bacon Bits - with your left join on `acctCTE` `on a.CUST_ID = c.CUST_ID and b.CUST_ROW_N = c.CUST_ROW_N`, why join `b` and `c` on CUST_ROW_N but not `a` or does that not matter at all. Maybe I just need to spend some time with the code and digest it a little more?

Comment: My concern is that in my real world scenario I have about 10 tables, each has between 1 and 10 columns with 0 to 10 rows of data per column so I've got to be careful to implement this correctly :)

Comment: The response from Amit works even if I add more records to one of the tables. [SQL Fiddle Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/b85fc/1). Bacon Bits it seems I have to have the same number of records across tables otherwise I will miss some data. [SQL Fiddle Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/b85fc/3)